# Android app testing on huawei harmony based OS

Tags: android, android-studio, huawei-mobile-services, harmony

an android devolveper can test apps via android studio by connecting huawei mobile based on harmony os?

I am a beginner and start learning Android development. In my place we can get huawei new devices at affordable prices that's why I want to confirm if I buy huawei mobile based on harmony os will this work to test android apps connecting it to Android studio like a normal android cell.

Comment: I think the answer here is no. Or at least getting Android Studio to work with a Harmony OS device will probably be difficult at the very least.

Comment: If you want to develop apps for Haromny OS, I recommend that you read [their documentation](https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/develop/) to learn how. If you want to develop for Android devices, then you can use Android Studio and check out its documentation.

Comment: use HUAWEI DevEco Studio

Answer (score -1):

I recommend that you first choose what platform you want to develop for. It sounds like you are considering choosing between Android and Harmony OS. When you make this choice, then you can read the documentation that explain how to develop for each platform.

For Android: https://developer.android.com/docs

For Harmony OS: https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/develop/